# |ID|1|: added to deviceToken on parse.com and android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com to send push notifications to android devices and it worked once and it registered the device's `deviceToken` correctly but suddenly it started adding `|ID|1|:` at the beggining and the notifications don't get to the devices that have that and they do to the ones that were already there.

I don't remember changing anything and I don't have any idea where that came from.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out I was calling `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground()` before `ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(...)` in my `Application` subclass.

So I changed the order to

```
Parse.initialize(this, appId, clientKey);
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(...);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

and it started saving all the `deviceToken`s correctly.

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation You should call `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground()` as soon as possible (`after Parse.initialize()`).

Are You sure this is the solution? It seems for me that is not connected in any way.